# Laravel get value from array

Tags: arrays, laravel

Apologies noob question and I'm usually good at figuring this out.

I have an array with the values:

```
{
    "carriage": [{"Net":"586.54999999999995"}],
    "totalNet":[{"Net":"16734657.34"}],
    "creditCarrage":[{"Net":"9.5"}],
    "creditTotal":[{"Net":"5712.6999999999998"}]
}
```

I've tried to return to screen just the carriage net value however I get the error

> Undefined index: Net

From the attempt

```
return $stats['carriage']['Net'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Look carefully the 'carriage' is a 2 level depth array, the 'Net' is accessible like this:

`return $stats['carriage'][0]['Net'];`

Probably, you want to restructure the data.

Comment: I tried that but got the error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: it seems that `{"Net":"586.54999999999995"}` is an object. I could not tell as objects and associative arrays are represented the same in JSON.

However, you can access it like this :`return $stats['carriage'][0]->Net;`

Comment: I would second that and also say that you probably want to restructure your data. If you don't need an array of objects then you could convert it to a single object and return your output like `$stats->carriage->Net`or `$stats['carriage']->Net`